# How to overwrite vertex in JanusGraph

Tags: janusgraph

I am inserting some vertex with same properties, and in my eyes, they should be the same thing, but when i use `tx.addVertex(T.label, "phone", "value", mobile)` they are different vertexes in graph. So when I want to get something, I cannot get what I want.

Here is my code:

```
 for (i <- 0 until 500000) {
        val grap = JanusGraphFactory.open("d:\\janusgraph\\janusgraph-hbase.properties")
        val tx = grap.newTransaction()

        var mobile = ""
        if (i < 10) {
            mobile = "1370000000" + i
        } else if (i < 100) {
            mobile = "137000000" + i
        } else if (i < 1000) {
            mobile = "13700000" + i
        } else if (i < 10000) {
            mobile = "1370000" + i
        } else if (i < 100000) {
            mobile = "137000" + i
        } else if (i < 1000000) {
            mobile = "13700" + i
        }
        val rd = Random.nextInt(100)

        val phonev = tx.addVertex(T.label, "phone", "value", mobile)
        for (j <- 0 until rd) {
            val dev = "dev" + j
            val devv = tx.addVertex(T.label, "deviceid", "value", dev)
            phonev.addEdge("phone-dev", devv, "value", mobile + "_" + dev)
        }
        tx.commit()
        tx.close()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When u call `addVertex` it will always create a new vertex indeed, but you can assign to a var and set the property via the `property()` method instead.

Comment: so,i  can only  use g.V()  to find this vertex and addEdge ?